Laravel migrate on multiple databases within the same connection
In Laravel there is the option to run a migration on a specific connection as: php artisan migrate create_users_table --create=users --database=mysql.
Is there a way to run the migration on multiple databases within the same connection ?
Because on the same port, username, password, host i have multiple databases.
Thanks

Connection in laravel is not about database server, one connection = one database (as well if databases in one server)
